# Arduino-project with color sensor and rgb-led

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, rgb-led, project

I want to use a color sensor for my Arduino project with Arduino Uno to detect the colors red, green, blue, orange, yellow purple of leaves of paper and then light my RGB led in those colors. I have no errors in my code, but it fails for some reason :( Can someone help me?

here is the code:

```
#define s0 8        
#define s1 9
#define s2 10
#define s3 11
#define sensorOut 12

#define LED_RED 3   
#define LED_GREEN 5
#define LED_BLUE 6

// Variabelen voor de kleurwaarden
int red;
int green;
int blue;

const int RED_COLOR = (255, 0, 0);
const int GREEN_COLOR = (0, 255, 0);
const int BLUE_COLOR = (0, 0, 255);
const int ORANGE_COLOR = (255, 165, 0);
const int PINK_COLOR = (255, 105, 180);
const int PURPLE_COLOR = (128, 0, 128);
const int YELLOW_COLOR = (255, 255, 0);

int color = 0;

void setup() {
  // Zet de seriële communicatie op
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initialiseer de pinmodi
  pinMode(s0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorOut, INPUT);
  
  pinMode(LED_RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BLUE, OUTPUT);

  // Zet de frequentie van de kleurensensor op 20% (rode filter)
  digitalWrite(s0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(s1, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // Lees de kleurwaarden
  digitalWrite(s2, LOW);                                           
  digitalWrite(s3, LOW);                                           
  red = pulseIn(sensorOut, digitalRead(sensorOut) == HIGH ? LOW : HIGH);       
  delay(20);  
  digitalWrite(s3, HIGH);                                         
  blue = pulseIn(sensorOut, digitalRead(sensorOut) == HIGH ? LOW : HIGH);
  delay(20);  
  digitalWrite(s2, HIGH);  
  green = pulseIn(sensorOut, digitalRead(sensorOut) == HIGH ? LOW : HIGH);
  delay(20);  

// Controleer op verschillende kleuren
if (red > green && red > blue) {
  color = RED_COLOR; // Rood
} else if (green > red && green > blue) {
  color = GREEN_COLOR; // Groen
} else if (blue > red && blue > green) {
  color = BLUE_COLOR; // Blauw
} else if (red > green && red > blue && green > blue) {
  color = YELLOW_COLOR; // Geel
} else if (red > green && red > blue && blue > green) {
  color = ORANGE_COLOR; // Oranje
} else {
  color = 0; // Geen herkende kleur
}


  // Controleer op verschillende kleuren
  if (color == RED_COLOR) {
    setColor(255, 0, 0); // Rood
  } else if (color == GREEN_COLOR) {
    setColor(0, 255, 0); // Groen
  } else if (color == BLUE_COLOR) {
    setColor(0, 0, 255); // Blauw
  } else if (color == ORANGE_COLOR) {
    setColor(255, 165, 0); // Oranje
  } else if (color == PINK_COLOR) {
    setColor(255, 105, 180); // Roze
  } else if (color == PURPLE_COLOR) {
    setColor(128, 0, 128); // Paars
  } else if (color == YELLOW_COLOR) {
    setColor(255, 255, 0); // Geel
  } else {
    // Geen herkende kleur, zet de led uit
    setColor(0, 0, 0);
  }

  delay(500); // Wacht 500 milliseconden voordat je de volgende kleur controleert
}

// Hulpmethode om de RGB-waarden in te stellen
void setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
  analogWrite(LED_RED, red);
  analogWrite(LED_GREEN, green);
  analogWrite(LED_BLUE, blue);
}
```

Comment: What does “_it fails for some reason_” mean? What is the expected behavior of your sketch? What is the actual observed behavior? How exactly do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code, I see three points:

1. Your constants are not assigned the values that you think. `const int RED_COLOR = (255,0,0);` sets the integer constant to the value `0`, i.e. the last value of a comma-separated sequence, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69515298/assigning-tuple-to-an-int-variable-and-printing-the-variable). Instead, enumerate your color constants, i.e. set red=1, blue=2, etc. Or define a struct with three integer components.
2. The variable `color` will never be assigned the values `ORANGE_COLOR`, `PURPLE_COLOR` nor `YELLOW_COLOR`, because of the way you structured the expressions in the if-then-else block. If `red > green && red > blue`, the program will never even check whether `red > green && red > blue && blue > green`, because it already entered the first block. And `PURPLE_COLOR` is not listed in the upper if-else-block at all. Also, I would expect some `CYAN_COLOR` somewhere in there to cover the shades between green and blue.
3. What is the exact type of the color sensor? It seems strange to me that it transmits its data via the length of a pulse. If it doesn't, `pulseIn()` is the wrong method to use. If it really does, you may have a race condition here: I guess that writing to the pins `s2`/`s3` triggers the sensor to start the "data pulse", in which case `digitalRead(sensorOut)` may already return the "pulse state" instead of the "pre-pulse state" and therefore waits for a different pulse than it should. You'd need to first read `sensorOut` into a variable, then set `s2`/`s3`, then read your data via `pulseIn` using the variable you set before.

But without having the datasheet of the sensor/knowing the protocol of the sensor, this is all very volatile guesswork. Please improve your question by adding the sensor type (and maybe a wiring diagram) alongside an explanation of what you mean by "it fails". How exactly does it fail? Which part works and which doesn't?

You can also glean more insight into the state of your sketch by writing measured values to the serial monitor using `Serial.println`.